# Python 3.6 After converting tkinter to exe - SSH function stopped working

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

After I did the convert to exe, ssh(paramiko) function does not work anymore. It does not connect to the device.
I have included paramiko and socket packages.  Any Idea?

it is working in with non-converted version.

setup.py file

```
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys
includes = []
include_files = ["C:\\Python36-32\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll",
                 "C:\\Python36-32\DLLs\\tk86t.dll",
                 "C:\\Gustavo\\PyCharmPortable\\new\\cpass.ico",
                 "C:\\Gustavo\\PyCharmPortable\\new\\py2.py",
                 "C:\\Gustavo\\PyCharmPortable\\new\\py3.py",
                 "C:\\Gustavo\\PyCharmPortable\\new\\tn.py",
                 "C:\\Gustavo\\PyCharmPortable\\new\\file1.csv"]
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform == 'win32' else None

setup(name='Password Change', version='0.1', description='Password Change',
      options={"build_exe": {"packages": ["tkinter","paramiko","PIL","socket","telnetlib"], "includes": includes, "include_files": include_files}},
      executables=[Executable('cp.py', base=base)])
```

Comment: What is your full error traceback (if there is one)?

Comment: That is the problem.  there is no error. Just sits there and nothing happens.  Maybe a missing package?

Answer (score -1):

try including the socket.py/socketserver.py and the _multiprocessing.pyd/_tkinter.pyd/_socket.pyd, this is what worked for me.

```
include_files = [
             "C:\\Python36-32\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll",
             "C:\\Python36-32\DLLs\\tk86t.dll",

             "Python36/Lib/socket.py",
             "Python36/Lib/socketserver.py",
             "Python36/DLLs/_multiprocessing.pyd",                
             "Python36/DLLs/_tkinter.pyd",
             "Python36/DLLs/_socket.pyd",

             "C:\\Gustavo\\PyCharmPortable\\new\\cpass.ico",
             "C:\\Gustavo\\PyCharmPortable\\new\\py2.py",
             "C:\\Gustavo\\PyCharmPortable\\new\\py3.py",
             "C:\\Gustavo\\PyCharmPortable\\new\\tn.py",
             "C:\\Gustavo\\PyCharmPortable\\new\\file1.csv",
```